# Scala - Parsing a string with optional match

Tags: scala, parsing

I have this pattern:

```
val smilepattern = "([:]) ([-]) ([) | | | (])".r
val smilepattern(colon, dash, arc) = ": - |" 
println(colon + dash + arc)
```

my intention is to check the building of three `smiles`, but HOW I can say that the `dash ([-])` is optional? Because, a `smile` can be `:-)` and `:)`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make things optional by using `?` in regular expressions.

```
scala> ":  )".matches("([:]) ([-]?) ([) | | | (])")
res1: Boolean = true

scala> ": - )".matches("([:]) ([-]?) ([) | | | (])")
res2: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Great, but it's requiring 2 `spaces` between `: (space space) )`. I understand why but my app that will use such pattern doesn't generate spaces in case that `dash` is missing. Thanksss

Comment: How I can say: `if (dash is missing) val sml = signs.mkString("(double spaces)").trim else sml = signs.mkString("(single space)").trim`

Comment: probably like val sml = if (dash is missing) signs.mkString("(double spaces)").trim else signs.mkString("(single space)").trim